# SPFx -DO I need all of the node_modules for every new webpart I build?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, nodejs

I have noticed that every time I create a new SPFx web part, using Yeoman for generating a project, the folder size is 300+ mb. I noticed the majority of the size comes from the node_modules where all of the dependencies reside from jquery to weather. Is there any way to get a minimized version of these, or can I have one main version that references these from all other web part projects?

Answer (score 2):

You can add new web part on your existing solution by executing below command in the existing solution directory.

```
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
```

https://blog.mastykarz.nl/add-second-web-part-sharepoint-framework-project/